# Display more than one page at once jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

How can I display more than one page at the same time with jQuery mobile? I have a big page in "background", but when I click a button I want to show a settings menu (another jQuery page), maintaining the same background. It is possible to do?

EDIT: avoiding the use of `iframe` html element

Answer (score 2):

JQuery mobile is designed to display one page at a time. You can however display a popup ([see documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html)) that will be displayed on top of the current page, and can accommodate a menu

Comment: The menu is complex and has more then a page inside, can a popup be linked to another to simulate the transition between a page to another?

Comment: @user1875044 At the moment you cannot [chain popups](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html) (that is open up one popup from another).

Comment: In this link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/showing-multiple-pages-simultaneously it seems that the users has reached his (and mine) goal

Comment: afaik loadPage will insert the content of the page in the DOM and potentially enhance it, but it will not display it. If popup does not make it for you, I think you will have to handle displaying of pages by yourself (load and initalize them, then make them visible on top of current page)